# How can I change embed source with a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want is one HTML page filled with buttons to choose your flash game, and every button redirects to one page. This one page contains an embed and that's all. Since the buttons redirect to the same thing, I would just want to change the source on the embed. I don't completely understand why my code isn't working so feel free to make any suggestions.

**Game Chooser Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/stylesheet.css">
        <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
        <link type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="../Other/favicon.ico">
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <title>GridOff</title>
        <script src="../JavaScript/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="gamesrc.html">
            <input type="button" value="Dig to China" id="dtcpicker" class="flashpickbtn" onclick="srcDtc()">
        </a>
        <style>
            #dtcpicker {
                top: 10px;
                left: 10px;
            }

            .flashpickbtn {
                position: absolute;
                font-size: 1em;
                text-align: center;
                width: 120px;
                height: 60px;
                border: 3px solid #000000;
                border-radius: 2px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function srcDtc() {
                document.getElementById("gameplayer").src = "../Games/dig-to-china.swf";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Game Player Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/stylesheet.css">
        <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
        <link type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="../Other/favicon.ico">
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <title>GridOff</title>
        <script src="../JavaScript/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object>
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
            <embed id="gameplayer" src="">
        </object>
        <style>
            #gameplayer {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Game Changer page, you are trying to target the element on the Game Player page, but this won't work strictly with just HTML, because you have no way of carrying information between pages. You might be able to create a cookie, save info to that cookie, and read it on the new page, or use local storage perhaps. But if you placed the `<object></object>` on the Game Changers page, you would be one step closer for this to work, because the element with the ID "gameplayer" is in the DOM. The DOM can't read information on a page other than itself.

Comment: All of my CSS and JavaScript are stored in one file which I use in the head of every HTML page that I use for this program. In this way, I can open just the one page and edit CSS and JavaScript for every single page I make for this project I'm working on. I put the <style> and <script> in the question so you would be able to see. On the real page, the only <script> is in the head with a src="../JavaScript/index.js". Is this not linked?

Comment: Once you redirect/refresh the page you are on, it will reload and be just like you were never there (in this instance). If you add a button on the page that triggers the background to change to pink, one you refresh that page, it will be reset because that change needs to be saved somewhere. Databases allow you to store information so you can recall it in a different place, at a different time. As does cookies, that store small pieces of info that you can read after reloading a page or redirecting to another page on your site. So this isn't linked the way you are hoping it should be.

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ll look into implementing cookies. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @HarrisonReeves No problem. Just know that if someone clears their browser cache, the cookie will be cleared also!